# create subnetwork not connected to internet

Tags: networking

Say I have a frontend server that communicates with several backend computers to serve some sort of content. That's all nice, but connecting the backend to the frontend via a router would leave all computers connected to the internet. Is there any way to keep the backend off the internet on a seperate local network and just use the frontend to connect to the internet and serve content?

Answer (score 0):

This is offtopic for stack overflow, but I'll answer anyway. The way I see it, you have two possible solutions:

1. Install a second network interface card (physical or virtual) on your frontend server. One will have the public facing IP and will be connected to the Internet. The other will have a private IP; it will be connected to an internal subnet where the backend servers reside.
2. Connect both to the same network, but use a firewall on the backend server to limit the IPs allowed to connect to it.